# GCP Cloud Run: Disable default URL and use Custom Domain only?

Tags: google-cloud-run

Is it possible to disable the default URL like this `https://my-app-332mpca-uc.a.run.app` and only use my custom domain as defined in domain mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve that with custom domain. You can achieve something similar by adding a Load Balancer in front of Cloud Run thanks to [serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless).

As you do that, you have an IP that you can add to your registrar (similar to custom domain in fact). To remove the public access of the Cloud Run default URL, you can set the [ingress parameter of Cloud Run service to `Internal and Cloud Load Balancer`](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress).

And then, you have it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info, I will look into this

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to zombie this, but if you are just prototyping and don't want to pay for a load balancer just yet, you could just examine the `Host` and 404 requests where the host ends in `.app` (provided that isn't your TLD of course!).

Please note that this is a hack and guillaume's accepted answer above is the **proper** way to do it.

With that said, here's a crude C# workaround I've been using (put it somewhere in `Program.cs`):

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
   if (context.Request.Host.Host.EndsWith(".app"))
   {
      context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
      await context.Response.CompleteAsync();
      return;
   }

   // Carry on down the chain
   await next.Invoke();
});
```